# Compile variables.less file to where? FLAT UI

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, flatui

I'm pretty new to the use of .less files. I downloaded a FLAT UI bootstrap. Now I wanted to change the base color of the bootstrap and therefor I used the variables.less file. There I changed the brand-primary to an other colorscheme.
Now I read everywhere I need to compile this file. But to where do I need to compile this because there is no variables.css file available only there is a bootstrap.css file and flat-ui.css file. I'm I seeing something wrong here?
It's about this bootstrap: http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI

Comment: You need to compile the `flat-ui.less` file. It imports other .less files from the project, including variabless.less. A variables.less compiled to variables.css would be useles because there are no variables in CSS, these variables are meant to be referenced in LESS source code.

Comment: @pawel please add your comments as an answer, so this question get labeled accepted