# ASP.net: applying variables.less changes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm pretty new in the use of less files and I'm staked in the attempt of changing the value of some constants in variables.less.

I already tried many solutions like the ones described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30779267/compile-variables-less-file-to-where-flat-ui) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350779/bootstrap-variable-overriding-with-less).
I'm struggling because even if I change the variables.less file redefining the constants I want to change, the browser shows the same output as with the former variables.less, as it was not changed at all.

I recompiled with Web Compiler all the less files I modified. I also tried to use the "Build->Recompile all files in the solution" menu item, without success. I added the file to the compilerconfig.json using the right button menu item "Web Compiler->Compile File" and I tried also to run the compiler directly from the Task Runner Explorer. Everything seems to work during compilation, but when I restart the web site (I'm still using the IIS Express to debug the website) the changes aren't applied.

What I'm trying to change are the constants:

```
    @table-cell-padding:            8px;
    @table-condensed-cell-padding:  5px;
```

that change the style of a bootstrap table to a more compact table. I simulated with success this change modifying the padding values directly using the Chrome browser inspector. I did it with success also changing the padding in the style.css, that in the layout is now defined before the bootstrap.css:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

I've tried to create a new *custom.less* in a separate (../shared) folder calling the bootstrap variables.less file as in the following code.

```
    @import "../less/variables.less";

    @table-cell-padding:            5px;
    @table-condensed-cell-padding:  2px;
```

with no success.

Debugging using Chrome I've found that no matter what I do, the code inspection shows always the former values of the constants, even if these constants have been changed also in the variables.less file.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Just importing and compiling `variables.less` is not enough (if you test your `custom.less` result you'll see it's empty). You need to recompile the `bootstrap.css` itself (e.g. by importing `bootstrap.less` into your `custom.less`) if you want to override variables there... (then obviously use your resulting `custom.css` instead of the original `bootstrap.css`).

Comment: Thank you seven-phases-max. Even if the reply was not the one I was looking for, you inspired me the solution of the problem, opening my eyes about the checking the content of the bootstrap.css.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that the problem was another bootstrap.css file (in \bootstrap\dist\css) in a folder hiding the compiled one (in \bootstrap\less).

I had to set properly the compilerconfig.json generated with the Web Compiler to write over the bootstrap.css file pointed by the _Layout.cshtml.

So the operations I recommend to create a custom less file for variables are the following:

- create a custom.less file in the same or a parallel directory (ex.: ../shared) of the variables.less file; add in the custom less file the reference to the variables.less file and the new definition of the constant (ex.: cell padding for tables);

  ```
  @table-cell-padding:            5px;
  @table-condensed-cell-padding:  2px;
  ```
- add the reference to the custom.less file in the bootstrap.css file soon after the variables.less

  ```
  // Core variables and mixins
  @import "variables.less";
  @import "../shared/custom.less";
  @import "mixins.less";
  ```
- compile the modified less files with web compiler (install it from Tools->Extensions and Updates if you don't have it);
- check into bootstrap.css that the custom values are properly changed as the ones you set in custom.less;
- check in compilerconfig.json that the file bootstrap.css that you are creating with compilation is the same referred in _Layout.cshtml; In case, modify the outputFile of the json file to overwrite the bootstrap.css referred in the _Layout.cshtml file;
- rebuild and restart the website;